# Environment for editing/testing XML,XSL files locally?

Tags: xml, xslt, development-environment

Just wondering if anybody knows of an environment for running, testing, debugging xml and xsl locally.

Kind of like the way XAMPP can be used for web design.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a brief list of five of the more known XSLT/XML IDEs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There are a number of well-known XSLT IDE's**:

1. **The [XSelerator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xselerator/)** (free) -- I have been using this excellent tool for 10 years.
2. **[oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/)** -- probably the most extensive support for XSLT 2.0 plus Docbook plus good XML authoring tools
3. **[Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255810(VS.80).aspx)** --both VS 2010 and VS2010 come with an excellent XML editor and an XSLT Debugger/Transformer
4. **[Stylus studio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/)**
5. **[XML-SPY](http://www.altova.com/)**

**All of these tools support XML intellisense and debugging**, some support schema-directed editing.

Comment: thanks. another great answer. you offer a wealth of knowledge in this area Mr Novatchev. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I use Visual Studio - it has an excellent XSLT debugger.